# Re-load Android activity data

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am writing an Android app, part of which will be a survey involving multiple pages of checkbox question and answers. I have created an activity to display the question and options (from the DB) and what I want to do now is when i press the "Next" button it should just reload the current activity with the next question set from the database.

(the activity starts with `survey.getNextQuestion()` - so its just a case of refreshing the activity so it updates)

Im sure this is a simple thing to do -any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would start a new instance of the activity for the new question.  That way if the user hits back, it has the logical behavior of taking them back a page.

It is possible to update the same activity, but it is more complicated.

To open a new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("nextQuestion", x);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your onCreate method, you can pull the next question from the database.

Answer (score 1):

> Im sure this is a simple thing to do -any ideas?

It is pretty straight forward, yes. [Mayra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892709/re-load-android-activity-data/2892841#2892841) is perhaps the better one, however here is an approach that will achieve the functionality you specified.

You can use `findViewByID(int)` to identify the `View` objects in your layout that need to be updated, and assign the result to an attribute in your `onCreate` to allow you to access it later.

E.g.

```
aView = (View) findViewById(R.id.aview);
```

Your `survey.getNextQuestion()` can obviously be used to get the next question.

The question can then be placed into the UI by manipulating the `View`s you obtained in `onCreate`.

E.g.

```
aView.setText("your question/answer");
```

Depending on the number of answers you may need to programatically create/remove checkbox Views from your layout

E.g.

```
ViewGroup yourViewGroup = findViewById(R.id.yourviewgroup);
View yourView = new View();
//Configure yourView how you want
yourViewGroup.addView(yourView);
youViewGroup.removeView(yourView);
```

All of this functionality can be contained in a function that is called by the `onCreate` method and when the next button is pressed.

Don't forget to store the result of the previous question before refreshing ;)